# Multiple condition if fonction inside a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

i'm browsing SO and i can't find a solution to my problem, so i made a post.

I try to make a For loop with a If statement inside that have multiple conditions (at least 3) but it does not work and i can't wrap my head around it... i tried lot of things but nothing seams to work.

here is my code, simplified because in my actual code the values for a, b, c and d are random :

```
    a=[1]
    b=[2]
    c=[3]
    d=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    
    for i in d:
        if d>a and\
           d>b and\
           d>c:
            print("OK")
        else:
            print("not OK")
```

But no matter what i try, i always get this output :

```
not OK
not OK
not OK
not OK
not OK
not OK
not OK
not OK
not OK
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Al of ``a``, ``b``, ``c``, ``d`` are *lists*. ``[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] > [1]`` is false. Did you mean ``i > a[0]`` and similar?

Comment: yes but if i go with 'a=1' 'b=2' and 'c=3' i can't compare it with my list of intergers in d. TBH it drives me crazy. I don't know the way to compare a list of integers to specific ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this :

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

for i in d:
    if i > a and i > b and i > c:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("not OK")
```

```
not OK
not OK
not OK
not OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
```

Comment: oh.... THANKS A LOT ! I honestly think i need some resting time T T Of course it's i and not d that i have to compare. once again thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code:

```
    a=1
    b=2
    c=3
    d=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    
    for i in d:
        if i>a and\
           i>b and\
           i>c:
            print("OK")
        else:
            print("not OK")
```

Ouput

```
not OK
not OK
not OK
not OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
```

Comment: Yep thank you. It appears that i forgot the basics ahah

Comment: Can you please accept and upvote my answer so I get the points